# Python Dict List to Sum of ints

Tags: python, list, dictionary, casting, int

So I have a series of lists that I'd like to sum over and return each individual value of. The lists look like this:

```
'testRel.txt': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

This is my most recent traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./SeriesCount.py", line 24, in <module>
w.writerow(sum(series))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I know why it won't sum my values (they're not integers and therefore can't be summed), I'm just having trouble with the syntax of casting my list of key values to ints. Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import copy
import os
import sys
import glob

#get current working dir, set count, and select file delimiter
os.chdir('/mypath')

#parses through files and saves to a dict
series = {}
for fn in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(fn) as f:
        series[fn] = [1 for line in f if line.strip() and not line.startswith('#')]

print series

#save the dictionary with key/val pairs to a csv
with open('seriescount.csv', 'wb') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, series) 
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(sum(series))
```

Result should look like this:

```
'testRel.txt': 5
```

Comment: Clearly your `series` contains string values instead of numeric ones. What exactly is printed in `print series` line?

Comment: `sum(series)` does not sum the numbers in one of the lists, but the keys, which are strings. How do you want the result file to look?

Comment: @tobias_k added update to main body

Comment: @ŁukaszR. Print series line outputs the first line mentioned, i.e. 'testRel.txt': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Comment: Where does the `:` in the "result" come from? Are you sure it should not be one row of file names and then one row of sums? Or should that be a `,` and you want the pairs of filename and sum in the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues in your code -

1. When you do `sum(series)` , you are actually trying to sum the keys, not the values. Also, DictWriter's writerow expects a dictionary as the input, not a single value (which is what `sum()` would return, if it were to work at all, which wont anyway).
2. You should not be openning the file (for writing to csv in binary mode - `wb`) , open it in write mode - `w`.

Instead of doing - `sum(series)` - you should try dictionary comprehension to create the sums of each key/value pair.

Code -

```
with open('seriescount.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, series)
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow({k:sum(v) for k,v in series.items()})
```

Demo -

```
>>> series = {
... 'mytext1.txt':[1,1,1,1,1,1],
... 'mytext2.txt':[1,1,1,1,1],
... 'mytext3.txt':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}
>>> with open('seriescount.csv', 'w') as f:
...     w = csv.DictWriter(f, series)
...     w.writeheader()
...     w.writerow({k:sum(v) for k,v in series.items()})
...
8
```

The result in `seriescount.csv` is -

```
mytext3.txt,mytext2.txt,mytext1.txt
12,5,6
```

Comment: As a side note, the `sum` can be performed directly in the first `for`, saving the cost of lists and dict comprehension: `series[fn] = sum(1 for line in f if line.strip() and not line.startswith('#'))`

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at the documentation for the DictWriter class:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

There's a line there that reads: "Note that unlike the DictReader class, the fieldnames parameter of the DictWriter is not optional."

I believe your problem is in this line:

```
 w = csv.DictWriter(f, series)
```

Your `series` is a dictionary object. That's the wrong type for the constructor's parameter. What you want is a list of the dictionary's field names: you want the dictionary's *keys* (in the order you want the values printed). To me, the values in your dictionary do look like int values, so that's not the problem.